# C++ issue inserting to MYSQL: inserts into database but throws exception error

Tags: c++, mysql, class, exception

I am fairly new at Cpp. but I have been able to do everything that I have tried up to this point. Just making a small game that i can move characters around and store  their information into a database(MySQL). My code before was simple but did not have room for addition. I am trying to make a class for all my SQL functions and pass the SQL strings to them. my code now is...

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "function_include.h"


class CHARACTER_STATS
{
public:
string get_connection(string query_receive)

    try
    {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        //Create connection
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("localhost:3306", "root", "Jsafley1");
        //Connect to the MySQL Server
        con->setSchema("stats");

        //prepare for query request
        stmt = con->createStatement();


        //make the query dynamic to a variable. Can be passed by any 
function.
        res = stmt->executeQuery(query_receive);    
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        //cout << "#ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        //cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        //cout << "#ERR: " << e.what();
        //cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
        cout << "Error here";

    }

}
private:

};

   string character_create()
{
try {
    string name, health, action, mind, xaxis, yaxis;
    cout << "Enter your desired character name. " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\n You have 3 stats and 1000 pints to devide into each stat how 
you wish" << endl;
    cout << "Set your Health" << endl;
    cin >> health;
    cout << "Set your Action" << endl;
    cin >> action;
    cout << "Set your Mind" << endl;
    cin >> mind;


    string sendQuery;
    sendQuery = "INSERT INTO character_stats(player, health, actions, mind) VALUES('" + 
        name + "', '" +
        health + "', '" + 
        action + "', '" + 
        mind + "')";

    CHARACTER_STATS postQuery;
    postQuery.get_connection(sendQuery);

}
catch (sql::SQLException &e)
{
    cout << "Inserted but error... ";
}
}
```

Also, I am using Visual Studio Community, C++ Connector for MySQL, and Boost.

This information to be put into the database gets inserted. but then it stops the program and throws this exception...[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8F4i.png)

The error pops up at the very end of my code. Right before it is supposed to return to the main() function.

Am I missing something? or doing something wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of your error, but your code appears to be vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack, due to concatting your SQL query with user inputted values - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp - The SQL library you're using probably supports parametrized queries, which avoids this issue.

Comment: i am not really concerned about SQL injection as of right now. this is just a simple locally run project to better learn Cpp. I'll look into parametrized queries. I never heard of that term before.

Comment: you can use QSqlQuery query;  query.prepare("insert into TableName(ColumnName) values(:var);");   query.bindValue(":var", YourValueHere);

Comment: QSqlQuery is saying it is undefined. Do I need to #include a header for that?

Comment: Wait, I found out my issue. i changed the function in the class to:                  
       void get_connection(string query_receive)

Comment: Thank you to those who commented!